# NTLM authentication using CXF wsdl2java stubs

Tags: web-services, cxf, ntlm, wsdl2java

I have a web service protected by HTTPS with NTLM authentication and I generated a set of java stubs using CXF's wsdl2java tool by temporarily disabling authentication.  I am now attempting to use the Java stubs within an applet that connects to the web service with the authentication turned back on.  My intention was to edit the Java stubs to include authentication cookies from the browser's session into CXF client connection to the web service.  The only problem is that the stub merely calls "super()" on the Service class and it handles all of the connection on its own.  Does anyone know how to use CXF's java stubs generated from wsdl2java to connect to a web service protected by https and NTLM authentication?

here is the constructor stub:

```
public Visual_Service(URL wsdlLocation) {
    super(wsdlLocation, SERVICE);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

not that I've tried it but theres a description at the bottom of this page [cwiki](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html)

Comment: This is the canonical recipe.

Comment: yes, this is what I eventually ended up using actually.  I used the code at the bottom of the wiki and it works now.  I did have to modify the source of jcifs to allow for https instead of just http though.

Comment: If you would have spend 2 seconds investigating the URL and search for the document, you would have found it here http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html